# Random word pick based on the number of times that they were used

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of strings like this one:

```
std::vector<string> words ={"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"}; //and many more
```

The `code` randomise the vector ( in an auxiliary vector) and takes the first word from the auxiliary vector. To do this I use `random_shuffle`. So far, everything goes very well. But now, I would like to minimise repeated words. My idea is to save the number of times a word is used to in another vector of `<int>` and randomise the words based on some weights that depends on the number of times that a word is selected by the generator. The words used more times have a lower weight and, for instance, the words never used have maximum weight (`1.0` maybe). Is there something in `STL` that can do that? If not, does someone can help me on this hard task?
The task is:

- At beginning all words have the same probability (same weight) of being picked and the random function picks any word with equal weight;
- After first  pick, one of the words will have lower probability because it was already picked once, so,the random function will pick a random word from the list, but the one already picked will have lower probability of being picked;
- After some tries suppose that `word1` was picked `4` times `word2` `3` times `word3` `3` times and `word4` `0` times. The word with lower weight is `word1` and the word maximum weight will be `word4`. Based on the number of times that word was picked the random function will generate the weights and pick a word.

thanks in advance

Comment: What task do you need help with?

Comment: To take one random element, shuffle the whole vector each time to take only the first one seems wrong. [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::discrete_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) might help, something like

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

std::vector<std::string> words = {"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"};
std::vector<std::size_t> weights = {10, 10, 10, 10};

for (int i = 0; i != 12; ++i) {
    std::discrete_distribution<> d(weights.begin(), weights.end());
    
    const auto index = d(gen);
    std::cout << words[index] << std::endl;
    weights[index]--;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e386f67dae4a800c)